# "You are not authorized to access this operation"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, alexa-skills-kit

Using the aws `ask` utility program from the `alexa skills kit`, I am trying to deploy my skill to alexa. With a new account, I've added the key and secret key. I've given my account full admin rights from the dashboard. The web browser auth steps confirms that my login was successful but the console reports **401 - "call list-vendors error" : "You are not authorized to access this operation."** with no further instruction.

I am not using a proxy or a VPN either.

Comment: What `Default Region` did you enter?

Comment: Did you solve it? I have the same issue by running ask init.

Comment: @Fahim yes it turned out the other developer had not set up the account correctly. He used an Amazon account. By registering for an Amazon Developer Account and using the supplied creds from the developer console, it worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error because I had multiple profiles is ask-cli. It was picking  `default` profile, which had a different Amazon.com account. I used `--profile` flag to use the specific profile:

```
ask clone --profile myProfileName --skill-id 'amzn1.ask.skill.******-****-****-****-*********' --debug
```

Also using `debug` flag will tell the exact error.